# Duplicating and renaming files with a specific filename in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to duplicate a few hundred files (to the same directory) and rename them.

All these files have the same name.

E.g.

```
Z:/Directory/123/Photo.jpg
Z:/Directory/456/Photo.jpg
Z:/Directory/789/Photo.jpg
```

I need to duplicate these file, give them a new name, while keeping the original file.

So I will end up with 2 identical files but with different names, in the same directory.

```
Z:/Directory/123/Photo.jpg
Z:/Directory/123/Image.jpg
Z:/Directory/456/Photo.jpg
Z:/Directory/456/Image.jpg
Z:/Directory/789/Photo.jpg
Z:/Directory/789/Image.jpg
```

I would like to do this using Powershell, but other any methods will do just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem Z:/Directory -Recurse -Include Photo.jpg | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { Copy-Item $_ (Join-Path $_.Directory Image.jpg) }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\Directory\*\Photo.jpg | foreach { Copy-Item $_ (Join-Path $_.Directory 'Image.jpg') }
```